# MySQL SubQuery Conditional

Tags: mysql, subquery, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a rather complex view in MySQL and want to do a conditional, but it sems always to fail.

My view (simplified) is

```
Select entry AS Entry, ,(select count(`poitems`.`entry`) AS `count(poitems.entry)` from `poitems` where (`poitems`.`PurchaseOrder` = `purchaseorder`.`entry`)) AS `TotalEntries`, from purchase orders
```

this is OK but what I am trying to do is add something like

```
if ((select count(`poitems`.`entry`) = 0),'query.png',NULL) AS Queryflag
```

or just test the value of TotalEntries.

Help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well it is complex. Here is the full view (that works):

Comment: can't put in the full query (too long) but the bit that is of interest is that the purchaseorder table (the main one) has an index field called entry and the poitems table has a field called purchaseorder. Getting the total of the items in the poitems table if fine, it is just I want to conditionally show a graphic is the totalitems is 0. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: just slap up some create table statements or plop em in pastie.org

Comment: too long for this box so I will have a look at pastie.org

Comment: i didnt mean this box. you can edit your question (the little edit link)

Comment: I table is http://pastie.org/7910753

Comment: and the other is http://pastie.org/7910759

Comment: the actual view is at http://pastie.org/7910765

Comment: can you briefly explain the conditional you are trying to return. the if statement is messed up. what is the business simplistic explanation

Comment: on another note outside of auto_increment, all of your columns are nullable even the ones with non-primary keys/index. there is no chance for foreign key constraints, and data that must exist (outside of the FKI issue) can simply be null

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on the names of the columns in `purchaseorder` or `poitems` tables but the following should get you headed in the right direction:

```
select t.Entry,
case when t.TotalEntries > 0 then 'query.png' else null end as Queryflag
from
(
select po.entry as Entry,
count(*) as TotalEntries
from purchaseorder po
left outer join poitems poi on poi.purchaseorder = po.entry
group by po.entry
) t;
```